# Taylor series expansion of $\ln\frac{1}{1-\epsilon^n}$ w.r.t. $n$, when $0<\epsilon<1$, around $n\to 0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Could someone please explain why the Taylor series expansion of $\ln\frac{1}{1-\epsilon^n}$ w.r.t. $n$, when $0<\epsilon<1$,  around $n\to 0$, is $\ln(1/n)-\ln(\ln(1/\epsilon)) +R_n$, which is the answer that Mathematica gives. When I try to derive this answer myself, I get the zero-coefficient of the Taylor series as $\infty$ and all other coefficients as zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=\ln(1/\epsilon).$ As $x\to0,$

$$\begin{align}\ln\frac1{1-\epsilon^x}
&=-\ln(1-e^{-kx})\\&=-\ln(kx+o(x))\\&=-\ln x-\ln(k+o(1))\\&=\ln(1/x)-\ln k+o(1).
\end{align}$$

Comment: This resolves it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This works if $0<\varepsilon<1$ is *fixed* and $n\to 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
\log \left( {\frac{1}{{1 - \varepsilon ^n }}} \right) & = \log \left( {\frac{1}{{n\log (1/\varepsilon )}}\frac{{ n\log (1/\varepsilon )}}{{1-{\rm e}^{ - n\log (1/\varepsilon )}  }}} \right)
\\ & = \log (1/n) - \log \log (1/\varepsilon ) + \log \left( {\frac{{ n\log (1/\varepsilon )}}{{1-{\rm e}^{ - n\log (1/\varepsilon )} }}} \right)
\end{align*}
and
$$
\log \left( {\frac{t}{{1 - {\rm e}^{ - t} }}} \right) = \frac{t}{2} - \frac{{t^2 }}{{24}} +  \ldots 
$$
as $t\to 0$.